# How to find sum in Mongo aggregate method with match in different collection in an array of object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to find the sum by matching array of object using mongoose. I have 2 collection such as

```
const accountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    groupId: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    account_no: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    account_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    opening_balance: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
    
})
```

And second collection as:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const AutoIncrement = require('mongoose-sequence')(mongoose);

const accountJournalSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    journal_no: {
        type: Number
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Users',
        required: [true, 'User ID is required.'],
    },
    groupId: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    receipt: [
        {
            account_no: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Accounts',
                required: true
            },
            debit: {
                type: Number,
                default: 0
            },
            credit: {
                type: Number,
                default: 0
            },
        }
    ]
})
```

And my aggregate method is:

```
await Accounts.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                $and: [
                    { groupId: {$eq: parseInt(req.params.group_id)} },
                    { 'Account_jour.groupId': { $eq: parseInt(req.params.group_id) } }
                ]
            }
        },
        {   unwind: '$Account_jour' },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from : 'account_journals',
                localField: '_id',
                foreignField: 'receipt.account_no',
                as: 'Account_jour'
            }
        }
    ])
```

I am getting error from the above statement:

> Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators

And after solving the issue I also want to find the sum of debit and credit.

Thank you!!

Comment: The pipeline stage is `$unwind` not `unwind`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
await Accounts.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [{ groupId: { $eq: parseInt(req.params.group_id) } }, { "Account_jour.groupId": { $eq: parseInt(req.params.group_id) } }]
    }
  },
  {   $unwind: '$Account_jour' },
  {
        $lookup: {
            from : 'account_journals',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'receipt.account_no',
            as: 'Account_jour'
        }
    }
])
```